# CRM 2011 Import of Price List

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can records of different entities be created on an import? 
I have custom entities that describe the product; like department, manufacturer, and category.

The requirement is to perform a single import that creates and updates records; 
this included price list items for (possibly) multiple price lists. 
The other requirement is to view all records that will be created/updated.

Currently I have an entity called **staging** that I import to.
A plug-in listens on **Create** and processes each record individually - creating/updating multiple entities.
Is there a better way to solve this problem? 

The other side of the equation is to view what will change in the system. 
I have another custom entity called **import**, a single record with the same sequence number as the corresponding import is created for each import.
An html web resource displays the changes that will be made in a list.
JavaScript on the web resource queries CRM (big imports may be a problem)
On the **import** entities's ribbon is a button called *process import*, which fires another plug-in (which was listening on **Create** of another entity, **internalprocessimport**, the JavaScript of the ribbon button creates a record of this entity - also with the original *importsequencenumber*), this plug-in processes all **staging** entities with the right *importsequencenumber*.

Answer (score 1):

When you say *view what will change*, are you referring to a text based log that lists what's been done? If so, you could add a field to the *staging* entity and have its plugin write to it, perhaps.

Just make sure to truncate the text mass so that the size of it will fit within limits of the maximum length of the text field. Otherwise you'll be puzzled by the error message that comes with that.

Also, when you create the entities, are you using *QueryExression* object? I believe CRM is supposed to get a better handling of multiple operations in UR12. Haven't tested it myself, yet, though.

Comment: Viewing what will be changed after the ribbon button has been pushed, that is before any 'real' records have been created. I have been trying to implement an html web resource that is dynamically populated by JS which queries CRM, so the text field max size is not an issue. I am using individual IOrganizationService.create(), update 12 is not installed yet; from what I understand update 12 gives IOrganizationService CreateMultiple.

Comment: AH, you mean like that. Got it. However, I'm not clear on what the problem is. You display the changes to come in the web resource but you'd like... What exactly would you like to happen?

Comment: I am having trouble getting the changes into the web resource. I am using OData. What I have is a list that is dynamically created with appendChild(item). I am going to give sdk.rest.js a try now. The JS will compare the staging records to live records and display the ones that are new in a list.

Comment: Why not throw in an attribute into each newly created tag with the info you need to tell the new ones from the old ones? Or am I missing the problem?